# Are Lift Pumps used in Bosch Kugelfischer mechanical plunger pump injection system?

Tags: engine, diesel, engine-theory, fuel-injection, fuel-pump

I know that Diesel Mechanical Inline Plunger injection pumps have a lift pump that supplies the main injection pump. Is it also the same case on Bosch Kugelfischer mechanical plunger injection pumps that work with gasoline instead of diesel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bosch Kugelfischer (I'll use "BK" for short going forward) mechanical plunger injection pumps for petrol engines were used across a variety of makes/models of vehicles from the late 60's into the mid-80's. They were derived from the diesel pumps as you suggested. A couple of vehicles which use the BK pump was the BMW 2002Tii and 2002 Turbo. [Below is from a technical supplement for the 2002 Turbo](http://www.bmw2002.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/bmw-2002-turbo-technical-supplement.pdf). You can see #3 is a fuel pump, which is separate from the #7 injector pump. #3 is a typical lift pump which provides the supply at low pressure to the injector pump, which, through the use of a cam mechanism, increases the fuel pressure so it can be injected.

[image]